# How to add the same vector to all vectors in numpy array without loops?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to plot a 3D mathematical expression using numpy and matplotlib:

The mathematical expression is:

`Z(x,y) = exp[(v - v_t)*(v - v_t)']`

while:

`v= [x, y]` and `v_t = [x_t, y_t]`

initiating vectors through the following code:

```
import numpy as np
CONST = 1
x = np.linspace(-5,5,20)
y = np.linspace(-5,5,20)
v = np.array([x,y])
v_t = np.array([CONST,CONST])
```

The question is, how can I execute the subtraction of v_t from each vector in array v, in a single command without looping?

the result should be something like so:

`v = ([-5, -4, ... , 4, 5], [-5, -4, ... , 4, 5])`

`v_t = ([1,1])`

`v - v_t = (x_i - CONST, y_i - CONST) = ([-6, -5, ... , 3, 4],[-6, -5, ... , 3, 4])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [63]: CONST = 1
    ...: x = np.linspace(-5,5,11)
    ...: y = np.linspace(-5,5,11)
    ...: v = np.array([x,y])
    ...: v_t = np.array([CONST,CONST])
```

The resulting arrays and shapes:

```
In [64]: v
Out[64]: 
array([[-5., -4., -3., -2., -1.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.],
       [-5., -4., -3., -2., -1.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.]])
In [65]: v_t
Out[65]: array([1, 1])
In [66]: v.shape
Out[66]: (2, 11)
In [67]: v_t.shape
Out[67]: (2,)
```

By the rules of broadcasting, we need to change `v_t` to (2,1):

```
In [68]: v - v_t[:,None]
Out[68]: 
array([[-6., -5., -4., -3., -2., -1.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
       [-6., -5., -4., -3., -2., -1.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code vector `v` has shape `(N, 2)` (where `N` is `20`). Now if you want to use the advantage of broadcasting in numpy, you can add a new axis inorder to reshape vector `v_t` into `(2, 1)` and then directly subtract `v_t` from `v`. This way -

```py
import numpy as np
CONST = 1
x = np.linspace(-5,5,20)
y = np.linspace(-5,5,20)
v = np.array([x,y])
v_t = np.array([CONST,CONST])
sub = (v - v_t[:, np.newaxis])
sub.shape # (2, 20)
```

Comment: why not subtract the (2,) from the (n,2) directly?  Not need to to reshape or transpose.

Comment: I just took you word that `v` is (N,2).  It is actually (2,N).  See my answer.  Oh, and by the rules of broadcasting, adding leading dimensions is automatic.

Comment: Be careful when using that `reshape(-1,2)`.  Look at the arrays before and after.  That is not the same as `transpose`.

Comment: Ah yes, I overdid it. Changing it right now!